# What is stdin and how is it being used with fscanf?

Tags: c, file, stdin, scanf, randomaccessfile

I dont understand the connection between stdin and fscanf

```
struct musteri{
    int no;
    char name[40];
    char surname[25];
    double arrear;

};



 int main() {

    struct musteri hesapBilgi={0,"","",0.0};

    FILE *ptr;
    if((ptr=fopen("eleman.txt","r+"))==NULL){
        printf("error");
    }

    else{
        printf("\n enter a no if you want exit enter 0 -->");   
        scanf("%d",&hesapBilgi.no);
```

scanf take a input and put the no in sturct musteri

```
while(hesapBilgi.hesapno !=0){


            printf("enter a surname name and arrear --->"); 
            fscanf(stdin,"%s%s%lf",hesapBilgi.surname,hesapBilgi.name,&hesapBilgi.arrear);
```

in here does the fscanf reading from data in file ? or  Something else is going on?

```
        fseek(ptr,(hesapBilgi.no-1)*,sizeof(struct musteri),SEEK_SET);
```

what is fseek doing ?

```
        fwrite(&hesapBilgi,sizeof(struct musteri),1,ptr);

        printf("enter a no :");
        scanf("%d",&hesapBilgi.no);


    }
    fclose(ptr);
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: This questions seem to be two (unrelated?) questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs (`man scanf`):

> The `scanf()` function reads input from the standard input stream stdin, `fscanf([FILE * stream, ...])` reads input from the stream pointer stream [...]

`stdin` is a `FILE*`. It is an input stream.

From the docs (`man stdin`)

> Under  normal  circumstances  every UNIX program has three streams opened for it when it starts up, one for input, one for output, and one for printing diagnostic or error messages.  These are typically attached to the user's terminal [...]

So

```
scanf( ...
```

in fact is equivalent to

```
fscanf(stdin, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
```

it reads formatted input from a stream.
and stdin is a standard input stream

and fseek is used for Sets the position indicator associated with the stream to a new position.

SEEK_SET is a flag which used for set position from beggining of file

Example of fseek

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "wb" );
  fputs ( "Fseek Hello World." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 9 , SEEK_SET );
  fputs ( "no" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

ouptut: Fseek Helno World

Comment: well why we need use the fseek the above example ? what happen if we don't use fseek ?

Comment: fseek is used for move FILE* position  so if u are not used fseek than output becomes Fseek Hello World.no